# How can you dye your frosting?

Tags: coloring

It may be closed for a lack of focus, but I'll give it a try. What are some pastry-friendly easy-to-obtain natural food dyes that you could use, for example, to give color to your frosting/icing (I mean other than red/purple, berries would do that)? It's not as simple as "take the fruit the colour you want to achieve". Bananas are yellow, but quickly turn brownish which is typically a color you want to avoid in food. Lemon is yellow, but mainly from the outside. The pulp is very pale in color. Tumeric is great, but would it be okay in pastry? I'm not sure. Orange, what about it? Apricots are no longer on sale, it's November. What about blue? Or green? Could you give me some ideas?

Comment: https://food52.com/blog/16265-how-to-make-all-natural-food-dyes-from-ingredients-in-your-kitchen

Comment: I know that there’s another question on here that covers more than just beets for coloring, but I’m on a phone right now and it’s a bit of a pain to search.  Search for ‘coloring’ instead of ‘dying’, I think

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/65823/67

Comment: Another one to look at - [my answer to *Hitting specific color of orange in a sponge cake*](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/88156/20413). I had fun addressing the turmeric/orange colour sub-questions (and it tasted pretty good too).